# Search not working in multi-language site

Tags: content-search, multilingual, azure-search

We are using Azure search. This is a website search. End user enters the keyword and the pages where it is present in the content, are returned as search results.

The functionality works fine when the page is browsed in the English version and the keyword is in English, but Thai-Thai is not working.

Is there any particular way to index the content for a multi-lingual site.

```
string index = string.Format("sitecore_{0}_index", Context.Database.Name.ToLower());

using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(index).CreateSearchContext())
{
  IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
              .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(ID.Parse(SitecoreUtility.GetHomeItem().ID)) &&
              x.Content.Contains(keywords) && x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);

  if (query != null && query.Count() > 0)
  {
     //process search result
  }
}
```

I have followed the solution [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/how-to-search-item-content-in-a-rendering-with-multilist-fields?rq=1) to build the _content field value.

The `if` condition fails for Thai search.

So, I modified it and found out that it actually returns no results for this:

```
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> querytest = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                  .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(ID.Parse(SitecoreUtility.GetHomeItem().ID)) &&
                x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
```

I'm only searching for page items that are under the "Home" item.
Does it mean, the Thai page items werent indexed.

Using Sitecore 8.2 version 3

Comment: Please try checking in whole content tree instead of a particulat node. There is a possibility that in that node Thai language items are not present.

Comment: Downvoted for abandoned post

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> querytest = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>(new CultureExecutionContext(Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo))
              .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(ID.Parse(SitecoreUtility.GetHomeItem().ID)));
```

Instead of your current query

```
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> querytest = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
              .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(ID.Parse(SitecoreUtility.GetHomeItem().ID)) &&
            x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
```

See if you get any results.

It's also worth looking into your search index to see what documents are in there, this blog should help you get startedf - https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2017/05/viewing-indexed-azure-search-content-sitecore/